# Installing packages through pip throws this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

[Erorrr message in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWgC4.jpg)

Hi Guys,

I'm trying to install various packages on my system. Trying to install any package through `pip3 install <pacakge_name>` and `python3 -m pip install <package_name>` methods leads to the same errors in the terminal.

Can you guys guide me towards some article/resource to begin to fix this mess?
My understanding is that I should start using venv to manage my packages to avoid such mess in the future. However, I need to fix this before I can go on and use venv to manage environments.

Comment: try pip install --no-cache-dir <package>

Comment: Tried that just now. Same result.

Comment: also make sure you have the latest setuptools and pip installed.